# What's the largest region MKMapView can show?

Tags: ios, uikit, mkmapview

I am try to show a big portion of the earth within a MKMapView view. Kind of like this:

[image]

However, the largest region I get to show is this:

[image]

I am setting the region to the `MKMapRectWorld`, which I assumed it would show the whole earth.

```
    MKCoordinateRegion worldRegion = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(MKMapRectWorld);
    self.mapView.region = worldRegion;
```

But it doesn't, any ideas why? Is there any way to show a biggest region?

Comment: I don't think this is possible since the map imitates the physical globe with infinite horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the map type to `MKMapTypeSatellite` will allow you to zoom out more but the standard map's zoom is restricted.

Comment: can U hav a look at this